# Hundreds of db consecutive insertions, and each query reads the latest value first (same table)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a "clients" table, with a "public_id" column. This column's value is generated right before a new client row is created, and its value represents: `some word + (total current number of clients + 1)`.

So the first client would be: `word 1`, the next would be `word 2` ... etc. This works fine when users add new clients the normal way via the app form. But when importing a huge list of clients, the generated value for "public_id" stays the same for multiple clients at row e.g `word 1` for 5-10 clients at a time!

I figured, since the queries are run consecutively very quickly, the query that counts the total number of clients before the insertions doesn't get it right ... or something to that effect.

What is the best way to handle this, in the db scope ... Table-locking? Transactions?

I am using Laravel jobs to handle the imports btw, and they run in parallel, so I cannot share the count across the jobs, it must be: stop -> give me the count -> +1 -> add client -> repeat.

Hope the issue is clear.

Comment: Without code examples it's hard to be sure what you're doing (and a minimal verifiable example would help a lot on that front).  It sounds like a race condition to me - if X clients follow your algorithm at the same time, the count will be the same for each of them.  Is there some reason you're not using an auto-incrementing column instead of trying to come up with your own incrementing value?

Comment: If you are doing a count in separate parallel threads, then it makes sense your count is not picking up the correct value. Why not have an auto-incremented column on your table, and use that to update the client id, if you really need a string. It feels like maybe you are using a string to encode meaning - what is 'word' for? If you are using it to represent some kind of info about the client, it would be much better to let SQL do it's job and have a column for id, and a column for whatever 'word' represents (type? server? etc)

Comment: The reason why I am not using auto-incremented value is that the "public_id" is based of a "template" value the user provides; it could be "Word + num. client + 1" or "num. client + 1 + Word", or "Random number + Word" ... etc. The structure of the value to be generated for the column is determined by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier if you had a column with 'word' and a separated autoincrement column?! This way you get yourself rid of this problem, letting the database management system deal with it for you.

Comment: I forgot to explain that the the value of this column is based on a "template" structure provided by the user. I am it's not strictly what I mentioned (Word + count), it could be one of many possibilities, including a random number, a branch code name ... etc